# Can sizeof() ever return a different value for the same type?

Tags: c, struct, byte, sizeof, vxworks

In C, on the VxWorks operating system, I am experiencing different return values on `sizeof` for the same input parameter.

I have only one declaration of a particular structure:

```
typedef struct Data{
    //contains ints, floats, int[], and float[]
} Data;
```

With two separate spawned tasks, each calling:

```
sizeof(Data);
```

the size appears different among the two calls.
One of the values returned back is smaller than it should be.

What could be causing this?
Why would `sizeof` return a different number of bytes on the same type declaration?

Comment: On the same machine with the same compiler? No.

Comment: Or someone added a #pragma pack(1) at the top of a header file, and forgot to add a #pragma pack(pop)

Comment: @AlecTeal *On the same machine with the same compiler? No.* Yes, the same compiler can produce different sizes for an object. Different command-line arguments and/or optimization levels can effect alignment and therefore size.  See Intel's `-align` option (https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/coding-for-performance-data-alignment-and-structures) and Oracle's `-xmemalign`, `-fast`, and `-dalign` options (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24457_01/html/E22003/cplusplus.1.html)  Compiling different compilation units with different command-line arguments can result in different sizes for an object.

Comment: (cont)  For example, if library code is compiled with a certain set of alignment-modifying command line arguments, but the calling executable is compiled with a different set of command line arguments, the executable and the library can interpret the contents of a structure differently.  (That's one good reason for making library APIs opaque.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite only having one declaration of the struct, the arrays inside the struct had their size specified by a macro.  The macro was re-defined in another file.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Name-mangling is an injective (1 to 1) function, given a name and some types an implementation ALWAYS maps it to the same thing.

So is `sizeof` - also size-of is simply a way for us to access the compiler's "amount of room for structure" knowledge of the struct, so if it could change this'd be REALLY REALLY REALLY bad.

Were your libraries compiled by the same thing? Are you sure data is the same? These are the things that could change - look there.

Side note:

> Size is pretty much fixed, but things align, like say we have an `int` and a `void*` - this is 12 bytes of data, but it may be aligned to 16 bytes so the `void*` is a multiple of 8 bytes aligned, this gives a large performance gain on some systems.
>   GCC and LLVM have both gone the same route and LLVM puts compatibility as a priority, GCC puts compatibility with old versions of GCC as a huge priority too. So no `sizeof` doesn't change.

Comment: It's years later but by dumb luck I followed this link from my user page. This is a proof by contradiction - suppose we could, then name mangling would either include this or be useless and linking would need to be aware too - which they're not, because it'd be absurdly difficult and cause linking problems. I then talk about packing. Note that alignof(T) always divides exactly sizeof(T)